# Diplay All Records, But Distinct?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to display all the records in `tbInventory`, but there are multiple duplicates on the records, specifically under the `colItem` column. Now what I'm trying to show are all the records in `tbInventory` but I want it in a way that it will only show an item once if it has a duplicate.

Now my current code displays this:

[image]

As you can see, its printing all the items with the `colItem` values of 'Access Point'. I only want the code to display the item 'Access Point' only once even if it has duplicates.

Now I can't simply use the **DISTINCT** function as I'm also using the code block for the printing of the data. Here's my current code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbDssInventory");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from tbInventory ORDER BY colItem");

if($result != NULL){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<table border=0 style=\"table-layout:fixed;\">";
            echo "<tr>";    
            echo "<td align=left width=15 style=\"word-wrap:break-word;\">";                                                            
            echo "<div class=\"hover_img\">";

            echo "  <a href=\"#\">";
            echo "  <img src='MAGNIFYINGGLASS.png' alt='Point' width='70%'><em>
            <object data=" .$row['colImage']. ".PNG width='850%' type=\"image/png\">
            <img src=\"default.png\" width='850%'>
            </object>";
                echo "</td>";

                echo "<td align=left width=160 style=\"word-wrap:break-word;\" style=\"word-wrap:break-word;\">";
                echo $row['colItem'];                                                                                                                               
                echo "</td>";

$itemname= $row['colItem'];
```

Is there a way to execute this?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbInventory GROUP BY colItem;

Comment: Let me know if `GROUP BY` helps you, so I can formulate it as an answer.

Comment: Add sample table data (as text), and also the wanted result. Tag the dbms used.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from tbInventory ORDER BY colItem");
```

Try this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from tbInventory GROUP BY colItem ORDER BY colItem");
```

You will get the item 'Access Point' only once even if it has duplicates. Hope it helps!

Comment: So you took my answer from the comments?

Comment: @Janno, don't be sorry. That GROUP BY is invalid. Wont run on newer MySQL versions.

Comment: @jarth how is that invalid?

Comment: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function. (Older MySQL versions doesn't care about this, and returns an arbitrary result.)

Comment: I just double-checked it. Upgraded MySQL from 5.x to 5.7 (don't know which version I had before that) and indeed, @jarth is right.

Comment: @jarth thanks for this. Took a dive into the specifics of this change and understood why the change actually is a good change.